renaming the unzipped files in s3 lambda function
const S3Unzip = require('s3-unzip'); 



  exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) { 
  
      const bucketname = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
      const filename = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));

    new S3Unzip({ 
    
        bucket: bucketname, 
        file: filename , 
        verbose: true, 
    }, function(err, success) { 
        if (err) { 
            callback(err); 
        } else { 
            callback(null); 
        } 
    }); 
} 

This is the lambda function code that I'm currently using to unzip the zip files in my s3 bucket.
My requirement is to rename the unzipped files before uploading to s3 bucket, how should I modify the above code to achieve this?
`
I tried using other packages like unzipper which require a filesystem to unzip and then I will be able to rename the filenames of each file. But I don't want to do that. I'm looking if it is possible by using the s3-unzip package itself.

The s3-unzip package does not provide a built-in way to rename files during the unzip process.
However, a possible workaround is archiveable by using AWS Lambda’s temporary storage in the /tmp directory as unzipper filesystem (up to 512MB):

Upload the zip file to the /tmp folder

Use s3-unzip to unzip the files.

Rename the file in the /tmp directory.

Upload the renamed file to the final S3 location.
 const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
 const s3 = new AWS.S3();
 const fs = require('fs');
 const path = require('path');
 const unzipper = require('unzipper');

 exports.handler = async function(event, context, callback) {
     const bucketname = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
     const filename = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));

     // Upload the zip file to the /tmp directory
     const zipFilePath = path.join('/tmp', filename);
     const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(zipFilePath);
     const s3Stream = s3.getObject({Bucket: bucketname, Key: filename}).createReadStream();

     s3Stream.pipe(fileStream).on('error', (err) => {
         callback(err);
     }).on('close', async () => {
         // Unzip the file in the /tmp directory
         const directory = await unzipper.Open.file(zipFilePath);
         for (let file of directory.files) {
             const content = await file.buffer();
             const originalName = file.path;
             const newName = originalName.replace('.txt', '_renamed.txt');

             // Upload the renamed file to S3
             const putParams = {
                 Bucket: bucketname,
                 Key: 'finalFolder/' + newName,
                 Body: content
             };

             await s3.putObject(putParams).promise();
         }

         callback(null);
     });
 };



